# Open3D point cloud transformation and project to rgbd image

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, open3d

I want to rotate the 3D point cloud using Open3D and project it to rgbd image but I find that Open3D uses 2 different types of point cloud.

One is `open3d.cuda.pybind.geometry.PointCloud` which has no attribute `project_to_rgbd_image` and another is `open3d.cuda.pybind.t.geometry.PointCloud` which has no attribute 'get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz'.

So my question is how can I use all 3 operations - rotation, transformation and projection to rgbd image function usnig open3d.

Answer (score 0):

Open3d has 2 apis for almost all 3d data-structures like PointCloud, Mesh, etc.

In this case, we have `open3d.geometry.PointCloud` which is legacy api and `open3d.t.geometry.PointCloud` which is the tensor or the new api.

Now, both legacy api and tensor api support rotate and transform methods which allows rotating the pointcloud.

Also, `get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz` is a static method and does not need Pointcloud class. You can call it as below:-

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

R = o3d.geometry.get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz((0.7 * np.pi, 0, 0.6 * np.pi))

dataset = o3d.data.PCDPointCloud()
# Notice, I am using o3d.t.io to get tensor pointcloud
pcl = o3d.t.io.read_point_cloud(dataset.path)
pcl = pcl.rotate(R, center=(0,0,0))

# Convert to legacy pointcloud to visualize using legacy visualization methods.
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcl.to_legacy()])
```

Also, notice that nowhere I have used `cuda.pybind`. This is not necessary and its internal. You should not use `cuda.pybind` or `cpu.pybind` in your imports.

P.S. The goal is to deprecate the legacy api however this will take some time.